# Getting the text and sender of an sms using smslib

Tags: java, sms, smslib

I want to get the text  and sender of the SMS read from the modem so that I can manipulate it as appropriate and then delete the read and used messages.this is the part of the code:

```
msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();
Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);
for (InboundMessage msg : msgList)
   System.out.println(msg);
   System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to stop service.");
   System.in.read();
   System.in.read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answers is :

```
text = msg.getText().toString();
sender = msg.getOriginator().toString();
```

Comment: where to put these lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer

String message = msg.getText();
String sender = msg.getOriginator();

Answer (score 0):

It is easy ..Edit the code as follows :

to get the text SMS:

`System.out.println(msg.getText());`

to get the sender of the SMS:

`System.out.println(msg.getOriginator());`

It is all ..